# jQuery file upload Resuming file uploads

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I am using the Jquery file upload basic-plus.html. I am not sure How to use the Resumable uploading functionality in the below code.

I see something like this according to the documentation but not sure How to use that with the basic-plus.html

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    maxChunkSize: 10000000, // 10 MB
    add: function (e, data) {
        var that = this;
        $.getJSON('server/php/', {file: data.files[0].name}, function (result) {
            var file = result.file;
            data.uploadedBytes = file && file.size;
            $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype
                .options.add.call(that, e, data);
        });
    }
});
```

I tried something like below. But didn't work.

**basic-plus.html**

```
 $(function () {
        'use strict';
        // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
        var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                    '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/',
            uploadButton = $('<button/>')
                .addClass('btn btn-primary')
                .prop('disabled', true)
                .text('Processing...')
                .on('click', function () {

                    var $this = $(this),
                        data = $this.data();

                    $.getJSON('server/php/', {file: data.files[0].name}, function (result) {
                        console.log('come here');
                        console.log(result);
                        var file = result.file;
                        data.uploadedBytes = file && file.size;
                        //$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call($this, data);
                    });

                    $this
                        .off('click')
                        .text('Abort')
                        .on('click', function () {
                            $this.remove();
                            data.abort();
                        });
                    data.submit().always(function () {
                        $this.remove();
                    });
                });
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: false,
            //multipart: false,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(avi|flv|wmv|mpg|mp4|mov|3gp|m4v)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 969932800, // 900 MB
            maxChunkSize: 2000000, // 2 MB
            // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
            // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
            // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            previewMaxWidth: 100,
            previewMaxHeight: 100,
            previewCrop: true,
        }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                var node = $('<p/>').append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
                console.log(node);
                if (!index) {
                    node
                        .append('<br>')
                        .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
                }
                node.appendTo(data.context);

            });
        }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
            var index = data.index,
                file = data.files[index],
                node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
            if (file.preview) {
                node
                    .prepend('<br>')
                    .prepend(file.preview);
            }
            if (file.error) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
            }
            if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
                data.context.find('button')
                    .text('Upload')
                    .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if (file.url) {
                    var link = $('<a>')
                        .attr('target', '_blank')
                        .prop('href', file.url);
                    $(data.context.children()[index])
                        .wrap(link);
                } else if (file.error) {
                    var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                    $(data.context.children()[index])
                        .append('<br>')
                        .append(error);
                }
            });
        }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            });
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
            .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');

    });
```

Comment: hi, did you find a solution to your problem above? I am trying to look at uploadedBytes for resuming the file upload as per the documentation but it did not work. Thank you!